Cannot convert value of type 'Request<Value>' to expected argument type 'Request<any Decodable>'
I am working on a project that contains the following protocol:
public protocol APIManaging {
    func execute<Value: Decodable>(_ request: Request<Value>) async -> Result<Value, APIError>
}

And I am trying to create a mock object like that:
public final class APIManagingMock: APIManaging {
    public var stubbedResult: Result<Decodable, APIError> = .failure(.networkError)
    public private(set) var spyExecuteRequest: Request<Decodable>?

    public func execute<Value: Decodable>(_ request: Request<Value>) async -> Result<Value, APIError> {
        spyExecuteRequest = request
        return stubbedResult
    }
}

where:
public struct Request<Value> {
    public var method: Method
    public var path: String
    public var queryParams: [URLQueryItem]?

    public init(
        method: Method = .get,
        path: String,
        queryParams: [URLQueryItem]? = nil
    ) {
        self.method = method
        self.path = path
        self.queryParams = queryParams
    }
}

I am getting these errors:

Cannot assign value of type 'Request<Value>' to type 'Request<any Decodable>'
Cannot convert return expression of type 'Result<any Decodable, APIError>' to return type 'Result<Value, APIError>'

Any ideas on how I can solve the issue?

Returning the mocked result
If you always just want to return a .failure, that's easy. Just move .failure(.networkError) inside execute.
public func execute<Value: Decodable>(_ request: Request<Value>) async -> Result<Value, APIError> {
    spyExecuteRequest = request
    return .failure(.networkError)
}

Because it is now in execute, the type parameter Value is in scope, so this will create the correct type of Result. The compiler will infer that you mean Result<Value, APIError>.failure(.networkError).
If you want to extract this into something reusable, you can write a generic method:
func stubbedResult<Value: Decodable>() -> Result<Value, APIError> {
    .failure(.networkError)
}

Then you can return stubbedResult().

If you want your mock to return a .success, you can hardcode some JSON string and try to decode it to an instance of Value.
let json = """
{ ... }
""".data(using: .utf8)!
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
return Result {
    try decoder.decode(Value.self, from: data)
}

Spying the request
As for spyExecuteRequest, you can write a type-erased protocol and have Request conform to it, since nothing in Request depends on Value.
protocol AnyRequest {
    var method: Method { get }
    var path: String { get }
    var queryParams: [URLQueryItem]? { get }
}

extension Request: AnyRequest { }

public private(set) var spyExecuteRequest: AnyRequest?

AnyRequest could also be a struct that simply copies all the properties of a Request<Value>
public struct AnyRequest {
    let method: Method
    let path: String
    let queryParams: [URLQueryItem]?

    // this also allows you to capture the 'Value' type
    let type: Any.Type
    
    init<Value>(_ request: Request<Value>) {
        self.method = request.method
        self.path = request.path
        self.queryParams = request.queryParams
        self.type = Value.self
    }
}

spyExecuteRequest = AnyRequest(request)

